# Как нормально реализовать функцию map в WEB3js

Tags: javascript

нужно с помощью метода map прогнать массив по функции смарт контракта и впихнуть полученные данные в другой массив, но при просмотре логов второго массива мне выдаются только адреса которые я вбил в первый массив, я так понимаю, куда-то нужно аккуратно впихнуть return result, перепробовал уже кучу вариантов. С js на вы

```
var tokenVesting = beneficiary.map(function(item, beneficiary) {
contract.methods.getDistributionContracts(item).call((err,result) =>{ console.log (result)})
});
console.log('vestingtoken',tokenVesting);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Изучать что такое асинхронное выполнение функций